# Trouble applying PHP 5.4 patch on Magento 1.7.0.2 Community

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, php-5.4, patches

When trying to apply the patch for PHP 5.4 compatibility of Magento 1.7.0.2, I get the following shell output:

```
user@server [~/public_html]# sh magento-php54-patch.sh
: command not found.sh: line 7:
'agento-php54-patch.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'agento-php54-patch.sh: line 9: `_check_installed_tools() {
```

I obtained the patch file by copy/pasting into my Windows text editor, then uploading to my CentOS web server. OS-specific text file formatting issues, perhaps?

As requested, first part of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Patch apllying tool template
# v0.1.2
# (c) Copyright 2013. Magento Inc.
#
# DO NOT CHANGE ANY LINE IN THIS FILE.

# 1. Check required system tools
_check_installed_tools() {
    local missed=""

    until [ -z "$1" ]; do
        type -t $1 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        if (( $? != 0 )); then
            missed="$missed $1"
        fi
        shift
    done

    echo $missed
}
```

Comment: show this script upto line 9, could be a problem with broken formatting  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852660/bash-sh-command-not-found

Comment: Posted above; couldn't get it to format correctly in comments.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHPStorm as IDE you can always apply the patch through "VCS \ Apply Patch ..".

Comment: Not using PHPStorm, unfortunately. :-(